# external dll visual studio C# error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am using external dll,but i am getting this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in ACRCloudExtrTest.exe.
>   Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'acrcloud_extr_windows_1.0.1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

i've put the dll in the project folder, also in system32 and sysWOW64 but nothing worked.

Here i am calling the dll:

```
class ACRCloudExtr
{
    public static byte[] CreateFingerprint(byte[] pcmBuffer)
    {
        byte[] fpBuffer = null;
        if (pcmBuffer == null || pcmBuffer.Length <= 0)
        {
            return fpBuffer;
        }
        IntPtr pFpBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        int fpBufferLen = create_fingerprint(pcmBuffer, pcmBuffer.Length, ref pFpBuffer);
        if (fpBufferLen > 0)
        {
            fpBuffer = new byte[fpBufferLen];
            Marshal.Copy(pFpBuffer, fpBuffer, 0, fpBufferLen);
            free_fingerprint(pFpBuffer);
        }
        return fpBuffer;
    }

    [DllImport("acrcloud_extr_windows_1.0.1.dll")]
    private static extern int create_fingerprint(byte[] pcm_buffer, int pcm_buffer_len, ref IntPtr fps_buffer);
    [DllImport("acrcloud_extr_windows_1.0.1.dll")]
    private static extern void free_fingerprint(IntPtr fps_buffer);
}
```

Comment: Is acrcloud_extr_windows_1.0.1.dll in the same folder as ACRCloudExtrTest.exe?

Comment: It doesn't tell you what DLL could not be found, only that this DLL could not be *loaded*.  If you have no idea what other DLLs this one needs then use a telephone or SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: yes  http://prntscr.com/8bt9i0

Comment: try putting it in the bin/debug directory if trying to debug bin/release if in release configuration.

Comment: still not working, i think @HansPassant is right, not loading

Comment: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) running in "Profile" mode is also great for finding missing DLL dependencies.

Comment: DllNotFound means it can't find the specified DLL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dllnotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx please paste the code where you call the DLL

Comment: @Jason i edited the post

Comment: i can make the call to the DLL without erro. One thing to note, the DLL I was able to track down (included in Streaming Audio Recorder) is of different size then yours. Mine reports it is version 1.0.1 so maybe try installing that software and swipe the DLL from its directory an drop it in your output folder. Also make sure you are building to 32 bit. Calling 32-bit DLL from 64-bit process will not work.

Comment: @Jason i changed dll 32-bit to 64-bit and i get another error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in ACRCloudExtrTest.exe

Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Comment: You will get that error if either the DLL or the Program is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit, are there any other references in your program? Any way you could send me that dll?

Comment: @Jason https://console.acrcloud.com/downloads/sdk/extr_windows here you can download it

Comment: thx, i just donwnload it again and it worked :)

Comment: Must have been a corrupt DLL. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that dll in references of your project right click on it -> **properties** -> **Copy Local** -> set to **true**.

Else if that dll is in project folder as a dll file add it to your project, right click -> **properties** -> **Copy to Output Directory** -> set to **Copy Always**.

**Build** your project.

Comment: It appears rather unlikely that a DLL which is used in a P/Invoke `[DllImport]` is in the project's assembly references list... (Mixed unmanaged/managed DLLs exist, but they are not very common.)

Answer (score 0):

-Inspect your DLL using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what other DLL it calls.

-Copy those DLLs in your project output folder. They might have dependencies of their own to resolve.